# protocol buffer - can't add list of string

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have program in Java. I need to save some values so i did this:

```
Parameters.entryParameters.Builder parameters = Parameters.entryParameters.newBuilder();

        parameters.setMaxNumberOfRules(maxNumberOfRules);
        parameters.setMaxPValue(maxPValue);
        parameters.setMaxRuleLength(maxRuleLength);
        parameters.setMinimumSupport(minimumSupport);
```

and that's work. In next line i did this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < genesOfPrimarySet.size(); i++) { 
                Parameters.entryParameters.primarySet.Builder primarySet =
                        Parameters.entryParameters.primarySet.newBuilder().setGenesOfPrimarySet(i, genesOfPrimarySet.get(i));
            }
```

Declaration of this list `List<String> genesOfPrimarySet`

So when i want to save this list i got exception. I wrote this base on official java tutorial protocol buffer and i don't know what is wrong.

Here is code of this exception http://pastebin.com/kW4Qp96x

Here is my proto file http://pastebin.com/exG3NjAm

Can sb tell how to save this String List ?

Edit: Finnaly i tried to make this with proto file only with one field:

```
repeated string genesPrimarySet = 1;
```

I dont know why but it doesnt' work in this example, when i change string to int32 then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf follows standard java List contract: `setXXX()` method *replaces* element at given position. Because initially the list is of empty length, IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown. To append elements, you need to use `addXXX()` method instead:

```
Parameters.entryParameters.primarySet.Builder primarySet = 
    Parameters.entryParameters.primarySet.newBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < genesOfPrimarySet.size(); i++) { 
    primarySet.addGenesOfPrimarySet(genesOfPrimarySet.get(i));
}
```

---

Even though this fixes the error, I doubt that you wanted to create a standalone `primarySet` message. I believe that you wanted to include `primarySet` as a field of `entryParameters` message:

```
message entryParameters {
  message primarySet {
    repeated string genesOfPrimarySet = 1;
  }

  required int32 maxRuleLength = 1;
  required int32 minimumSupport = 2;
  required double maxPValue = 3;
  required int32 maxNumberOfRules = 4;
  required primarySet genes = 5;
  ...
}
```

In this case, you do not need to create standalone Builder for `primarySet` -- you use builder provided by `entryParameters` builder:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < genesOfPrimarySet.size(); i++) {
  parameters.getGenesBuilder().addGenesOfPrimarySet(genesOfPrimarySet.get(i);
}
```